# Tcpdump packet-PID correspondence

Tags: windows, windows-7, tcpdump

So I've installed winpcap and use windump:

```
E:\>windump -i 2 -B 5000 -n -s 0 -l -C 1 -W 10 -e -q -X
windump: listening on \Device\NPF_{9718B3B1-6C96-4431-889B-2B1A37BED06E}
01:25:23.029278 00:19:5b:42:7b:b0 > 00:1e:8c:39:ea:64, IPv4, length 85: 83.140.172.212.6669 > 192.168.1.5.49266: tcp 31
        0x0000:  4520 0047 0070 4000 3706 8113 538c acd4  E..G.p@.7...S...
        0x0010:  c0a8 0105 1a0d c072 8272 c7b3 5be0 19fc  .......r.r..[...
        0x0020:  5018 0b08 c556 0000 5049 4e47 203a 706f  P....V..PING.:po
        0x0030:  7274 3830 632e 7365 2e71 7561 6b65 6e65  rt80c.se.quakene
        0x0040:  742e 6f72 670d 0a                        t.org..
```

How do I know, which process sent/got this packet? How can I know the PID?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, WinDump doesn't support that (and tcpdump doesn't support it on any flavor of UN*X, nor does Wireshark on any OS).

However, recent versions of [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) do.  It's free-as-in-beer, and has a GUI (which may be a bug or a feature in your case).

Comment: Guy is correct. And if you prefer, NetMon comes with `nmcap.exe`, which is CLI version.

Answer (score 0):

On windows:

```
netstat -on
```

on Unix:

```
netstat -pn
```

wou will see the connections and PIDs

Comment: But probably the connection can be already closed between I parse the tcpdump line and launch the netstat. How can I be sure, that I won't miss the localip:port before it dissapear or be rewrited by some new connections?

Comment: I am not a windows person, but I believe you can write a PowerShell scrip to tigger netstat as soon as windump captures a packet